# File format/extension not preserved inside gzip file when compressed using java

Tags: java, compression, gzip

I tried compressing a file to gzip format.
File format/extension of the source file is not preserved inside the compressed .gz file.

I used the following java code to gzip the file.

I am able to get file format inside the `.gz` file if `toFile = test.csv.gz`

but the file format is not available if `toFile = test.gz`

My concern is that I don't want to use the source file format in the name of the `gzip` file.

Code:

```
public void gzipFile(String fromFile, String toFile) throws IOException {



    GZIPOutputStream out = null;
    BufferedInputStream in = null;


    try {
        // Open the input file
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fromFile));

        // Create the GZIP output stream
        out = new GZIPOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(toFile)));

        // Transfer bytes from the input file to the GZIP output stream
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        //Complete the entry
        out.flush();
        in.close();


        File newFile = new File(toFile.replace(".log", ""));
        System.out.println(newFile);
        File file = new File(toFile);
        file.renameTo(newFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // log and return false
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                // Complete the GZIP file
                out.finish();
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ignore) {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `GZIPOutputStream` just compresses data, it doesn't store "file entry" information like a `ZipFile` would

Comment: GZip is purely a compression scheme, NOT a multi-file archive format.  There is no internally stored filename, which is why normally files named `x.y` are compressed to `x.y.gz`.

Comment: Actually there can be and often is a filename stored in the gzip header, but it is not used by default when decompressing.